# Shuffle list in certain order recursively

Tags: python, recursion

I'm trying to shuffle lists recursively in a certain order.

I have:

```
def shuffle(list1, list2):
    a = []
    if len(list1) == 0:
        a += list2
        return a
    if len(list2) == 0:
        a += list1
        return a
    else:
        a += [list1[0]]
        list1.pop(0)
        a += [list2[0]]
        list2.pop(0)
    return a += shuffle(list1, list2)
```

Comment: Is your problem that it's returning `none`?

Answer (score 3):

Your central issue is that you're not returning your recursive call.  Cleaning up some of the nominally-unused locals in your code gives:

```
def shuffle(list1, list2):
    a = []
    if len(list1) == 0:
        return list2
    if len(list2) == 0:
        return list1
    else:
        a.append(list1.pop(0))
        a.append(list2.pop(0))
    return a + shuffle(list1, list2)
```

Of course in the above cleanup it's clear that you don't even need the `a` accumulator:

```
def shuffle(list1, list2):
    if len(list1) == 0:
        return list2
    if len(list2) == 0:
        return list1
    else:
        return [list1.pop(0),list2.pop(0)] + shuffle(list1, list2)
```

demo:

```
shuffle([1,2,3],[4,5,6])
Out[35]: [1, 4, 2, 5, 3, 6]

shuffle([1,2], [6,7,8,9])
Out[36]: [1, 6, 2, 7, 8, 9]
```

As an aside, this mutates the input lists, which isn't generally desirable.  You may be better served by using slicing instead of `pop`ping elements off:

```
def shuffle(list1, list2):
    if len(list1) == 0:
        return list2
    if len(list2) == 0:
        return list1
    else:
        return [list1[0],list2[0]] + shuffle(list1[1:], list2[1:])
```

Comment: Pretty! Great work pairing the indices until one list is empty, then returning the full list. I don't think I would have thought about that.

Comment: > "You may be better served by using slicing instead of popping".

Doesn't each slice generate a copy of the original list minus one element? It's pythonic but seems like a lot of overhead.

Comment: @Isogen74 yes.  I assume that if you're using recursion in python you don't care about performance :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import chain

def shuffle(list1, list2):
    if len(list1)==len(list2): return list(chain(*zip(list1,list2)))
    # if the lists are of equal length, chaining the zip will be faster
    else:
        a = []
        while any([list1,list2]):
            for lst in (list1,list2):
                try: a.append(lst.pop(0))
                except IndexError: pass
        return a
    # otherwise, so long as there's items in both list1 and list2, pop the
    # first index of each (ignoring IndexError since one might be empty)
    # in turn and append that to a, returning the value when both lists are
    # empty.
```

This is not the recursive solution you were looking for, but an explicit one is generally faster and easier to read and debug anyway. @DSM pointed out that this is likely a homework question, so I apologize for misreading. I'll go ahead and leave this up in case it's enlightening to anyone.

Comment: Since the OP repeatedly mentioned recursion, I suspect this is an assignment question for which a `zip`-based solution isn't going to help.

Comment: @DSM I'll be honest, I skimmed the question. Recursive solutions are nearly never correct, but inevitably academic in nature. I don't understand....

Answer (score 0):

> How can I make this function work these cases using a recursive model?

For each step in your recursion where the two lists are non-empty you are creating a new temporary array "a", but then not doing anything with it.

You need to pass the list you are storing the result in by reference down the recursion chain (preferred - it's zero copy), or return the list fragment and append this to your result array as you unwind the recursion (functional, but needs a new list object to be created each time, which is slow).

Answer (score 0):

Generator version, just because generators are awesome ^^

```
def shuffle(a,b):
    A = iter(a)
    B = iter(b)

    while True: 
        try:
            yield A.next()
        except StopIteration:
            for j in B: 
                yield j 
            break
        try:
            yield B.next()
        except StopIteration:
            for j in A:
                yield j
            break

print list(shuffle(a,b))
```